# Connecting the C++ class with the LUA table

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to connect my 3d engine to a lua (5.1) parser.
For example, I have a LUA class of a vec3 and I have a C++ class of a vec3. I want them to work with eachother.

This is (part) of my C++ class:

```
class vec3
{
public:
    vec3() {}
    vec3(float _x, float _y, float _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}

    vec3 operator+(const vec3 &b)
    {
        return vec3(x + b.x, y + b.y, z + b.z);
    }
    float dot(const vec3 &b)
    {
        return x * b.x + y * b.y + z * b.z;
    }

    float x, y, z;
}
```

This is the (limited) lua version:

```
vec3 = {};
vec3.__index = vec3;
local mt = {}
mt.__call = function(class_tbl, ...)
    local obj = {}
    setmetatable(obj, vec3);
    vec3.init(obj, ...);
    return obj;
end
vec3.init = function(obj, x, y, z)
    obj.x, obj.y, obj.z = x, y, z;
end
setmetatable(vec3, mt);

function vec3:__tostring()
    return "(" .. self.x .. ", " .. self.y .. ", " .. self.z .. ")";
end

function vec3:__add(b)
    return vec3(self.x + b.x, self.y + b.y, self.z + b.z);
end

function vec3:dot(b)
    return self.x * b.x + self.y * b.y + self.z * b.z;
end
```

I think the question is quite obvious: I want to be able to use vec3's in my C++ code, for example to position nodes or other stuff and then I want to be able to make these available in LUA where the LUA-programmer can do math with the vec3's and send them back to C++. So I also want to be able to construct a vec3 in LUA and send it to C++ where it is understood as a vec3 class.

To achieve this, I think I need to construct the above LUA table in C instead of in LUA and I need to create a function "push" and "pop" to send them to LUA and retrieve them from LUA.

But all my trials fail.

Can anyone help me get this to work?

Dirk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create a userdata on the Lua stack in C++ and use that as the object. You can fairly simply placement new into it and arrange the metatable from C++. Of course, this is hideously type-unsafe, amongst the other huge holes in the Lua system.

Comment: I have tried that earlier, using the user data, but I got stuck after trying to add methods to it. I could add all the operator overloads, but I couldn't add a "dot" function to it. Help?

Comment: This is in short what I did:
- I declared my class by creating a metatable vec3 and adding things like __tostring, __index, __newindex, __call, ... in it.
- With the __index, I was able to request x, y, z from LUA
- With the __newindex, I was able to set a new x, y, z from LUA
But when I tried to add a "dot" function, the dot-call got into the __index call.

Comment: @scippie: That's because object:method() is object.method(object), and object.method invokes __index. You need to set up __index to cope with both variable accesses and method accesses.

Comment: I understand, but how do I do that?

At this moment, my lua__index function checks for the userdata, gets the index-parameter from the stack, and checks what it is. If it is x, y or z, it returns the value. If it is dot... how do I handle this? (I just printed out the stack when inside the dot-call, it doesn't contain the second object)

Comment: @scippie: You just return the cfunction that is dot. Lua will handle the rest for you. `object.method(object)` = `getmetatable(object).__index("method")(object)`- that is, the __index call is only expected to return the function.

Comment: Right! I was just getting to that same conclusion myself. And I just tried it and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @scippie: If this answer helped you to solve your problem, and you even accepted it, then why in the world wouldn't you also consider it good enough to upvote it?

Answer (score 2):

Why not try to use C++ packages like luabind or luabridge? In those you you can access any lua data from C++ and vice versa.

Comment: That would probably work yes, but I have yet to find one library that doesn't require me to include a lot of libraries I don't use.

Comment: Both don't require any additional library, AFAIK.